# How to override css class for responsive design without using !important

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I have a class assigned to span.
For desktop version this span has top: -25px and left: -5px.
For mobile version I need to change this same class for the same span to the values top: -10px and left: -3px.

How to achieve this without using !important ? Below is code :

```css
  .display {
  top: -25px;
  /* Need to change the values for mobile phones. */
  left: -5px;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .display {
    top: -10px;
    /* This style is not applied and overruled in browser */
    left: -3px;
    /* This style is not applied and overruled in browser */
  }
```

```html
<span id="lbTest" class="display">text</span>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: try using `span.display` in the media query.

Comment: This worked !!! Thank you. Just curious, how did adding span.display in media query make a difference ?

Comment: With what you've provided, I can't see why it would not override your styles. See [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-x1zawb). The css should be specified in the [order](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#cascading-order) you've shown above (if two rules have the same weight, the latter specified wins).

Comment: @user2294434 well it just specifies the element more clearly. The more specified an element is, the more priority it gets in stylesheet. That's how I understand it. It doesn't override `!important` though. And @CraftedPod also got a point, the order in which the css is written makes difference. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the main css in media query with min-width: 768px and add the mediatype (screen)

```html
<span id="lbTest" class="display">text</span>

<style>
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
.display {
top: -25px; 
left: -5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
.display {
top: -10px; 
left: -3px; 
}

}
</style>
```